# References about the history of Bosnian/Croatian/Serbian after the break-up of Yugoslavia

Tags: historical-linguistics, reference-request, history, bosnian-croatian-serbian

What is considered the best reference (papers/articles/books) that discusses the Bosnian/Croatian/Serbian language and outlines its history after the break-up of former Yugoslavia in the early 90s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone was curious, I've had a little visit to the library and found that [Robert Greenberg's](http://www.unc.edu/~rdgreenb/) wonderful book [Language and Identity in the Balkans: Serbo-Croatian and its Disintegration](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Language_and_Identity_in_the_Balkans.html?id=eXcrtSUnaPIC&redir_esc=y) is an excellent resource if you're interested in the language situation in the Balkans after the break-up of Yugoslavia.